# I'm not able to log in Tomcat Manager App

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication, unauthorized

I have read a lot of topics in stackoverflow for solve my problem, but none was useful.

When I tried to log in Manager App ([http://localhost:8080/manager/html][1]) using a lot of different configurations, but I always obtained **401 Unauthorized** after attempted to log in using the rights credentials.
I restarted the tomcat server a couple of times.

This is my last configuration in conf/tomcat-users.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx, manager-status, admin-gui, admin-script"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

This is the part related to tomcat-users in server.xml

```xml
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>
```

This is my configuration:
Apache Tomcat: Version 7.0.40 64 bit
Tested on Chrome 26

If there is something else useful that I forgot, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything looks good to me . Can you try with only below role. <user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />

Comment: One ubernoob thing that got me... the sample <user> tags in tomcat-users.xml start in a commented block by default.. make sure to remove them from that. XD

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From tailing **[tomcat-root]/logs/catalina.out**, I observed that you are using a locked username **"admin"**

```
06-May-2014 16:47:41.828 WARNING [http-nio-192.168.0.51-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm.authenticate An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "admin"
```

You should try with a better(non guessable) username.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="TomcatAdmin" password="secpa55wd" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

This should definitely work for you.

Comment: As mentioned in below answer, it is must required to restart the server to reflect the credentials of user changes in tomcat-users.xml file.

Comment: Restarting the service picked up the user name/pass changes for me.

Comment: note also that in case of NetBeans + Tomcat integration the location of the configuration files not the default one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591134/cant-access-manager-app-in-tomcat-8#27594468

Comment: This is definitely the answer, change your username and and password. Try with another browser if you can't open 'Manage App' tab

Answer (score 3):

Check syntax and start-ending tag. i did stupid mistake when i started work on java. 
This line was working for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomcat-users>
 <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
      <role rolename="manager-script"/>
      <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
      <role rolename="manager-status"/>
      <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
      <role rolename="admin-script"/>
      <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 2):

Configuration looks fine for me . can you please try with below **tomacat-users.xml**.

```
<tomcat-users>
  <user name="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui" />
</tomcat-users>
```

Please restart the server after change.

Comment: Having the same problem. It logged me in once but stopped, Every configuration is fine in my xml. Just confused.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions above probably solved your problem.The locked user solution tipped me off on my issue.

Something weird I noticed... Don't know how it happened.

After installing a new tomcat7 I ended up with a "tomcat-users.xml" file owned by user root and group root.

I found out because catalina.out contains a few lines like  "javax.naming.NamingException: /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Permission denied)"

After changing file ownership to user "root" & group "tomcat7" fixed my login issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you try any of the other Answers and then there is no difference, you may need to *clean your Tomcat* and then try again.  These are my clean commands (not sure how general they are):

```
rm -R $TOMCAT_HOME/work/Catalina/<host>/*
rm -rf $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/<app name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Also verify that the tomcat-users.xml you are editing actually corresponds with the instance of Tomcat you are running.  If you have multiple installations, but only one running, make sure you are editing the file at the correct location.

When you run startup.bat (or startup.sh), the script will output the CATALINA_* environmental variables.  If the paths do match the current working directory you are running from, it is a good bet that you have been editing the wrong tomcat-users.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't change anything. just replace below configurations to `/etc/tomcat9/tomcat-users.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
              
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,tomcat" /
</tomcat-users>
```

Then restart tomcat server by using `sudo systemctl restart tomcat9`

use this url to log manage-app admin http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html

Answer (score 0):

In my case the password had special characters, that needed to be XML encoded before being added to the `/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` file.

The tool that I used for the encoding was https://coderstoolbox.net/string/#!encoding=xml&action=encode&charset=us_ascii

Answer (score 0):

If you are using XAMPP follow the below steps

1. Go to XAMPP and Click on Config infront of Tomcat

   [image]
2. Then select tomcat-users.xml in the popup
3. And when it opens on an editor paste the following inside
   tomcat-users tags with your preferred password. Which will be as follows

```
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

4. Then restart the tomcat server from XAMPP.
5. And open the tomcat using the browser and you can give the user name and password as you given in the config file above, In my case, username = tomcat and password = password

Answer (score 0):

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
              version="1.0">
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <user username="tomcatuser" password="tomcatpassword" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,tomcat,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
</tomcat-users>
<!-- -->
```

**
tomacat 7+ version need to set manager rolse as manager-script,manager-jmx, manager-status
Then restart tomcat `sudo systemctl restart tomcat8`

Answer (score -2):

1.Goto C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 7\conf\tomcat-users.xml
open it with notepad
2.and add following tag inside   tag

```xml
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

3.on browser enter :
http://localhost:9090/manager/html
enter username:tomcat password:tomcat