# Can't access Manager-app in Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, tomcat8, manager-app

I read many similar problems here, but whatever I do, I can't login to manager app. What I have done.
 1. I edited the `tomcat-users.xml` by adding

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-gui,admin-script"/>
```

2. I started Tomcat (V.8) with Netbeans
3. I went to localhost:8084 (netbeans set the port to 8084) and I clicked "manager app".
4. In the prompted window, I put admin and admin and it doesn't login.

In the properties of the server in Netbeans, there are different credentials. I put the same to both of them (to tomcat-users.xml and there in Netbeans) and still nothing happens.
**Every time I make a change, I always restart the Tomcat** (no error occurs).
**EDIT** 
 When I try to run my application (the default one, when you create a project in Netbeans), I also can't login, so this messages comes up `Deployment error: Access to Tomcat server has not been authorized. Set the correct username and password with the "manager-script" role in the Tomcat customizer in the Server Manager.
See the server log for details.` 
However I have added the above in the tomcat-users.xml ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're editing the correct file.  NetBeans will create it's own copy of the configuration files, so you may have two or more tomcat-users.xml files.  In my case on my windows machine, the Tomcat launched by NB uses
C:\Users\DevServer\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\apache-tomcat-8.0.3.0_base\conf

Also, try simplifying and create a user with just the manager-script role.  Then tell NB about that user and pw in the Services/Servers/Connection credentials.  Example:

<user username="tomcat_m_script" password="pwhere" roles="manager-script"/>

Comment: It was in front of me all the time!!!!!!!! At properties in Tomcat server was written `C:\Users\~~~\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.2\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base` . I was editing the wrong file.. thank you!