# Unable to log in in Tomcat 8.5.24 Manager even without user and password set

Tags: apache, tomcat, tomcat8

I work with an application which uses Apache Tomcat 8.5.24 in a Windows Server 2012 or superior as the foundation to run a webpage. I have already installed and successfully made the whole system work in accordance with the steps of an installation manual.

Lately I needed to install the system again in a client but, contrary to previous cases, I've simply being unable to access Tomcat's manager page (127.0.0.1:8080/manager) with a browser.

I attempted many solutions found on the web on how to counter this issue, most of which involving changing the settings inside `tomcat-users.xml`, with no effect. I even came to the point of abandoning the idea of having a user and password set (the installation wizard says they are optional) and even so the pop-up requesting user and password keep showing and no manager is open. I did fresh reinstall even with a different installer (to check if it was corrupt), copied and pasted the `tomcat-users.xml` file from a different sucessfull installation, granted all possible permissions (the only real difference this time is that I'm installing remotely, but that shouldn't be a problem since the installation itself uses administrator rights) and the problem persists.

What other thigs could I try to solve this issue? Here are some links I consulted:

- [Link 1](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/177179-unable-to-access-tomcat-manager)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671858/im-not-able-to-log-in-tomcat-manager-app)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042235/tomcat-7-manager-how-to-authenticate)
- [Link 4](https://serverfault.com/questions/342312/tomcat-not-accepting-username-password-for-manager-gui)
- [Link 5](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27614847/Apache-Tomcat-7-0-21-username-password-not-working.html)
- [Link 6](https://coderanch.com/t/555293/application-servers/Unable-login-manager-GUI)

By the way, the Tomcat installation is unconnected to any NetBeans or similar software.

Comment: Are the other applications than manager accessible ? Do you have a Tomcat error page or a browser error page ? And on what OS do you run Tomcat ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell well applications such as firefox and notepad++ are also installed, but nothing related to web development such as Eclipse or NetBeans. About error page, the traditional 401 error if I click "Cancel" in the login popup. Running in Windows Server.

Comment: You installed with admin rights, but does the account running Tomcat have enough rights to read tomcat-users.xml ?

Comment: @EugèneAdell yes, the have. the mentioned solutions above include adding any possible rights to the account.

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem was found: for whatever reason, when I installed an Oracle stuff in the same PC, it was configured to listen to the same gate (8080) as Apache was configured, leading to the problem. It was just a matter of shutting down the Oracle service and I was able to access the Tomcat Manager. For reasons unknown, rebooting the Oracle service later didn't cause any more conflicts (maybe it automatically found another gate to listen to once detecting 8080 was already in use).